# Is there a way to extract live price quotes from a flight ticket website?

Tags: python, database, api, live, rapidapi

I need to know the live prices of plane tickets to calculate the cheapest route. Does someone know a way to extract this data? (Without Skyscanner Flight search - this doesn’t work) I’m writing the program in Python.

Comment: Yes, there is a way, and yes people know such ways, depending on what web site it is. No, we will not write code for you. Please read [ask]. If you need general theory about e.g. how to retrieve data from web sites, I would start by putting words like that into a search engine. Otherwise you should at least try to show some code, and explain exactly what API you are trying to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can track live prices of plane tickets by web-scraping or crawling. There are several frameworks in python for web-scraping. The most famous ones you can use are:

1. Beautiful soup
2. Selenuim
3. Scrapy
4. Requests

Link to Beautiful soup Documentation- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/